# Usar swing timer correctamente para ocultar Jlabel

Tags: java

Necesito ocultar un Jlabel con Swing Timer después de 5 segundos, el problema esta principalmente en que una vez que el Timer comienza, este al parecer no se esta deteniendo en ningún momento, ya que al usar el botón Mostrar por segunda vez, el Jlabel desaparece casi instantáneamente, que estaría faltando en este código para que se cumpla lo mencionado?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class respuesta extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    public respuesta() { 
        initComponents();
        label1.setVisible(false);
    }

public void ocultar(){
        int delay = 5000; //millisegundos
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                 label1.setVisible(false);
           }
        };
     new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}

private void btnMostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        label1.setVisible(true);
        ocultar();
} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new respuesta().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar que se repita, simplemente invoca el método [`setRepeats`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats-boolean-) de [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) con `false`; Es decir:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, evt -> {
    label1.setVisible(false);
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Más información en [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Gracias Paul, tu sugerencia funciona perfectamente.